# Custom 403 page for specific RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to make a specific 403 message (or page) for one specific set of RewriteCond in my .htaccess file in Apache 2.2. I have never seen this done, but it seems as though it should be possible.

The relevant part of my .htaccess access file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

As you can see, I just block them from access if the user agent matches my RewriteCond.

**A little more details**

This works great for blocking the offending bots, but we run into a slightly annoying problem. Our site is accessed by many very technical people. They do a lot of programming on their own and often use browser plugins like "User Agent Switcher".

I want to provide a more meaningful message in this specific instance. So that they know to change "User agent switcher" to a normal browser. Rather than just providing the normal 403 page, I would like a friendlier message here.

I know I could pass this to our scripting engine, pull out the user agent and pass custom headers, but it seems like this might have a more elegant .htaccess solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... why not just redirect to a custom 403 file? and in that html file you put what you want. The bot will always get sent there too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/errorpages/403.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* /errorpages/403.html [R,L]
```

Comment: That is really quite close to what I need. The one issue I ran into was the fact that the condition you mentioned above excludes accessing the 403 page. You get stuck in a loop and the browser errors out. For others accessing this answer, can you modify your answer to use an errorpages directory for the 403 (because the root level is blocked as well by your statement) and then put this as the first condition: `RewriteRule ^errorpages - [L,NC]`   If you do that, I tested and it works. I will upvote you after that gets fixed.

Comment: @Terry yes, you're quite right. I fixed it so it shouldn't cause a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a *custom* 403 error page, you could just make the same user agent check in your error page and display the appropriate response. Or, set a specific environment variable (eg. `SPECIAL_ERROR`) in .htaccess and check for this in your error page. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,E=SPECIAL_ERROR:1]
```

This avoids the "redirect" round trip.

Then, in your 403 error page... (PHP example):

```
if (getenv('SPECIAL_ERROR')) {
    // friendly error
} else {
    // Default 403
}
```

Comment: That is actually pretty useful. I had no idea you could set special environmental variables in htaccess like that.